# Authenticate Google Drive with Replit

Tags: api, uri, drive, replit

So I am trying to use an OAuth 2.0 Client to authenticate my replit project. It gives me the link in the replit console to the web page, but says it is an invalid request when I reach the page.

The issue now relies in that I cannot figure out which URI I need to use, these are the ones I tried (Jumpedia is my project name): [Authorized URIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubpRO.png)
I also tried entering ":80" for the port that replit uses. Does anybody know which URI I should be using for replit?

Comment: Ok when I click "If you are a developer of this app, see error details.", it always tells me:

Sie können sich nicht in dieser App anmelden, weil sie nicht den Google-Richtlinien für OAuth 2.0 entspricht.

Wenn Sie der App-Entwickler sind, registrieren Sie den Weiterleitungs-URI in der Google Cloud Console.
Request details: redirect_uri=http://localhost:50181/

Problem with that is, that the port always changes. What do i do?

Comment: Have you tried port 443 or https://  ?

Comment: I didn't try 443 yet